# threading.Lock() performance issues

Tags: python, multithreading

I have multiple threads:

```
dispQ = Queue.Queue()
stop_thr_event = threading.Event()

def worker (stop_event):
    while not stop_event.wait(0):
        try:
            job = dispQ.get(timeout=1)
            job.waitcount -= 1
            dispQ.task_done()
        except Queue.Empty, msg:
            continue

# create job objects and put into dispQ here
for j in range(NUM_OF_JOBS):
    j = Job()
    dispQ.put(j)

# NUM_OF_THREADS could be 10-20 ish
running_threads = []
for t in range(NUM_OF_THREADS):
    t1 = threading.Thread( target=worker, args=(stop_thr_event,) )
    t1.daemon = True
    t1.start()
    running_threads.append(t1)


stop_thr_event.set()
for t in running_threads:
    t.join()
```

The code above was giving me some very strange behavior.
I've ended up finding out that it was due to decrementing waitcount with out a lock

I 've added an attribute to Job class `self.thr_lock = threading.Lock()`
Then I've changed it to

```
with job.thr_lock:
    job.waitcount -= 1
```

This seems to fix the strange behavior but it looks like it has degraded in performance.

Is this expected? is there way to optimize locking?
Would it be better to have one global lock rather than one lock per job object?

Comment: What is setting or incrementing `job.waitcount`?

Comment: By the way: you should use `except Queue.Empty as msg:`. The syntax with the comma only works in python2, while the `as` works in python2.6, 2.7 and 3+. It's also more consistent with the rest of the language when you want to catch more than one type of exception.

Answer (score 1):

About the only way to "optimize" threading would be to break the processing down in blocks or chunks of work that can be performed at the same time. This mostly means doing input or output (I/O) because that is the only time the interpreter will release the Global Interpreter Lock, aka the GIL.

In actuality there is often no gain or even a net slow-down when threading is added due to the overhead of using it unless the above condition is met.

It would probably be worse if you used a single global lock for all the shared resources because it would make parts of the program wait when they really didn't need to do so since it wouldn't distinguish what resource was needed so unnecessary waiting would occur.

You might find the PyCon 2015 talk David Beasley gave titled [*Python Concurrency From the Ground Up*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MCs5OvhV9S4) of interest. It covers threads, event loops, and coroutines.

Comment: is there a known impact of using lock in terms of performance?

Comment: if multiple locks are used intstead of one, does it have any more impact?

Comment: You could measure how long it takes to acquire and release a `Lock` by using `timeit` in a (single threaded) test program. This will tell you the impact doing it has, which would have to be multiplied by how often it is done. However the won't include any waiting the might be required if there was more than one thread trying to gain exclusive access simultaneously or how long it might be held by each thread prevent the others to run—which is all application specific.

Comment: I don't think the number of locks matters. It's how often they're used and how much contention (waiting for it to be released) goes on. I wanted to also mention that one way to break the processing down into concurrent pieces is often mirrored by doing the same sort of thing to the data being processed—separating it into chucks that can be processed as an independent unit. Another thing is that to achieve true concurrent execution you should look into using `multiprocessing`, where each process runs in its own address space and with its own copy of the interpreter, so the GIL is a non-issue.

Comment: i understand that point (when to use multithread vs multiprocessing) the problem is the code which needs to be parallelized depends on shared information. are you saying multithread the parts only up to when it doesnt use that shared info? and the update of the shared info is single threaded?

Comment: Not exactly. Multithreading is entirely an illusion unless you're doing I/O because only one thread of Python code ever runs at the same time due to the GIL—so there's no gain in splitting a task up into computational chunks, just additional overhead. Using shared info from multiple threads isn't an issue, you don't even need a `Lock`, but _changing_ it from multiple threads requires them. There _are_ ways to share information in multiprocessing, but you'd want to limit it because it also involves extra overhead. Sorry but I can't teach you concurrency in the context of a single SO answer.

Comment: i know when to use multithread vs multiprocessing, dude. lol my only question was if there is any impact on using locks. Iam doing I/O ops using multithread, its just that it requires updating of shared info....

Comment: No worries dude (or dudette). All anyone can do is make abstract recommendations without knowing more of the specifics. As you mentioned, you might be able to `Queue` the updates of the shared information and have a separate thread which does nothing but locks the shared object and updates it. In addition you might be able to batch updates into groups so as to minimize the locking of the shared resource.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to answer your question based on your code. Locks do have some inherent cost, nothing is free, but normally it is quite small. If your jobs are very small, you might want to consider "chunking" them, that way you have many fewer acquire/release calls relative to the amount of work being done by each thread.

A related but separate issue is one of threads blocking each other. You might notice large performance issues if many threads are waiting on the same lock(s). Here your threads are sitting idle waiting on each other. In some cases this cannot be avoided because there is a shared resource which is a performance bottlenecking. In other cases you can re-organize your code to avoid this performance penalty.

There are some things in your example code that make me thing that it might be very different from actual application. First, your example code doesn't share job objects between threads. If you're not sharing job objects you shouldn't need locks on them. Second, as written your example code might not empty the queue before finishing. It will exit as soon as you hit `stop_thr_event.set()` leaving any remaining jobs in queue, is this by design?